# How to handle script time out error in asp classic

Tags: asp-classic

hi i am making a **script** in classic asp to generate a static file for some images to include into several pages on my site. i want to run that script one time in a day in **classic** asp any help please thank you

this is my sitemap generating script

```
dim fs,f,first,second,css   
        set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
        set f=fs.CreateTextFile("D:\ideal_v3_local_live\trunk\sitemap-reviews_1.5.html",true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a longer interval before the script times out with Server.ScriptTimeout

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_scripttimeout.asp